# How to config Linter for React Native?

Tags: react-native, eslint, linter, eslintrc

I made a React Native App (made by create-react-native-app).
I installed the eslint linter, but I got no idea how can I config it?
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-native)
I don't have the slightest idea where to put the:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "react-native"
  ]
}
```

config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

type in your directory where you want to use it

```
  eslint --init
```

After running eslint --init, you’ll have a .eslintrc file in your directory.
there can you config whatever u want

furtehr information on:

- [eslint gettin started](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started)
- [eslint-plugin-react Github](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react)
- [eslint-plugin-react-native Github](https://github.com/Intellicode/eslint-plugin-react-native)

Comment: my pleasure :) have fun with it ^^

Comment: and please mark as answer if i could help you with your problem